# Protractor: chromeDriver version 78 is throwing error that it only supports chrome version 79

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

I am using protractor with selinium webdriver. My chromeDriver version is 78.0.1 and chrome version is Version 78.0.3904.97. Both version matches and there should not be a problem, However running protractor protractor.conf.js throws a very wierd Error saying **This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79**. This is super weird because Chrome version 79 has not even launched yet

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your webdriver-manager version
it should be "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7" (i.e. latest stable version)

this error is caused by "^13.0.0-beta" which download chrome 79

[image]